# Persisting immutable objects to a relational database

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, relational-database, immutability

I've seen certain object-oriented experts advise that domain objects (POCOs) should be immutable.

That is, their state should be entirely determined at construction, and changes to state should require creating a completely new instance.

But say I'm persisting to a relational DB using an ORM - how do I determine which properties to persist, and how do I reconstruct the domain object based on data in a database?

For example, say I want to write this object to the database:

```
class User
{
    private string _emailAddress;

    public User(string emailAddress, string password)
    {
       // ... generate hash & seed
       _emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public string PasswordHash { get; private set; }

    public string PasswordSeed { get; private set; }

    public bool ValidatePassword(string password)
    {
       // validate it against the stored hash
    }
}
```

In the example above, I want to store the state of the object and retrieve it later. This means storing the PasswordHash, PasswordSeed and EmailAddress.

But the structure of the class prevents me from doing so.

- PasswordHash and PasswordSeed - I can store them, but what happens when I want to read them back from the database and reconstruct the object? There's no constructor parameters to pass them to, and I can't even construct the object without them because 'password' must be supplied and I don't know what the original password was. I can't set the 'PasswordHash' or 'PasswordSeed' properties, because they're 'private set'.
- EmailAddress - I can't store it because even though it's part of the object state, it's marked private and can't be accessed internally.

Yes, I could just make every property in the object public and read/write. But then, where's my encapsulation and immutability?

See, I wanted to store the password as a hash/seed and hide the emailaddress for a reason. I wanted to enforce a certain workflow into my domain objects.

But when it comes to storing them, I have to undo all those constraints and turn my domain objects into dumb key/value stores, with no constraints.

---

The underlying problem, it seems, is that relational databases have no concept of encapsulation. Every column in a table is 'public' and every value is 'mutable'.

So does this mean I have to throw out relational mapping altogether if I'm to have an immutable domain model? Or is there some well-known strategy for getting around this that I just don't know about yet?

Comment: I am not sure that I understand the problem... which properties are calculated, which need to be stored... ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good at explaining this stuff :P I've updated the question. Is it a bit clearer now?

Comment: yes - see my answer... if you need further information/idea just comment :-)

Comment: NHibernate. Can assign Private/Protected properties/fields.

Comment: What's the problem with writing another constructor?

Answer (score 3):

First of all - statement that domain objects should be immutable is wrong.
Only **value** objects should be immutable. User most likely is an entity.

Usually ORM`s uses some tricks to workaround this issue.

E.g. NHibernate leverages proxy libraries like [LinFu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx) to silently sub-class every class You have mapped with dynamically created ones. Doing this, it attaches handlers for every method that checks if state has been modified and triggers persisting changes of dirty entities.

NHibernate forces mapped objects to have protected, argument less constructors, all properties and methods to be overridable. Object is created "empty" through this constructor and state is set through overriden properties.

Answer (score 1):

Private Fields can be serialized too - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

In you case you want to serialize the values to a DB and also read them back...
There are a couple of ways to do that, for example:

- Implement 2 static methods as class member which can access all internal/private fields and thus serialize and reconstruct any field in the class
- Implement some Interface for serialization/deserialization which you can use as a parameter to the static method to lessen the dependency between the serialization/deserializeton process and the class

EDIT - as per comments:

In the static methods you can freely choose which fields to persist in DB and how (binary, XML or as one column per field etc.). Just implement your serialization/deserialization interface accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can read into serialization and deserialization of objects and store the data that way in your database (some of these are language specific so may not work cross-language). If you want to store all the fields that is. This will solve your password problem but would  pose a security risk if someone were to gain access and deserialize your instances and get the plaintext password (if it's stored in the object).

Here's a basic example of how to do it : http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Serialization-in-C.html

Comment: Interesting solution. Security wouldn't be an issue because the password wouldn't be stored, but would be hashed immediately upon construction of the object. However this solution works with binary streams, not with relational storage. I'm looking for a way to persist to a relational database (e.g. SQL Server), if such a thing is possible. If not, maybe I'd better just give up on immutability and make my objects dumb key/value holders.

Comment: You could create a table for each class and you can store binary data in the database. (Use Id's or names to create relational links and then just retrieve the binary data and deserialize it)

Comment: Would it have to be binary serialization? What if I serialized with XML, then converted each XML element to a database row name and stored the value that way?

Comment: That works as well, but XML can be placed as a Column type so you don't even have to do that much work :)

Comment: If you are seroiusly considering that, why use a relational database where tables have columns and datatypes, indexes and optimization etc... I wouldn't want to be the guy who had to write an efficient reporting interface to that database.

Comment: Precisely because I want a reporting back-end in the future. Why wouldn't you want to be the guy writing a reporting interface? Why does it matter how the data gets from the domain objects into the relational DB, as long as it ends up there, and is structured correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you decouple your domain layer from your data layer.  In other words:

1. Make a **data layer class** that corresponds directly to your User table's columns with all public getters/setters, a parameterless constructor, and no behavior.
2. Make a **domain layer class** which has the behaviors (i.e. methods), no public setters (if possible, in order to avoid the [Anemic Domain Model](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) anti-pattern), and minimal public getters.
3. Create a **mapper class** to map between the two.
4. (Optional, but good if this is a larger app.)  Make sure that only the domain class (or ideally its interface) is accessible to the outside world.  The mapper and data classes are not for public consumption so don't expose them.

Problem solved!  It seems like a pain to write all the mapping code (and you will need to test it because mapping is very error-prone) but in the end, it'll solve the headache caused by trying to server 2 purposes with one class.

Comment: What you're suggesting sounds quite doable. I am a bit confused about how a service-layer might fit in with all this. Basically I'll have a web front-end and a 'scraper' back-end. I'd like to have a service layer serving both of the above. In this case, the web front-end and the scraper would be working with 'service contracts' rather than 'domain objects'. Hence, my domain objects would harldly ever get used. Is this a normal design? Or am I missing something? Perhaps domain-driven design isn't the correct choice for this kind of problem? (Sorry for overloading you with questions :))

Comment: No problem!  Typically, your UI hits your app service layer (preferably by contract instead of implementation).  The app service layer will maybe retrieve the domain object from a repository, perform an operation or two, then save the domain object in the repository (again, better by contract than implementation).  You'll want to use domain driven design if your domain is more behavior-centric (has a lot of verbs) than data-centric (has a lot of nouns).